# How to create a session-like variable on Meteor Server?

Tags: session, meteor, tmp

I want to create a single tmp directory using [tmp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp). And I would like to to reference the path of this directory inside Meteor.method implementation...

```
import tmp from 'tmp';

tmp.dir(function _tempDirCreated(err, path, cleanupCallback) {
 if (err) throw err;

 // Store path as a session variable

});
```

I know that Session is only available on the client, and the thing is [tmp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp) is only available on the server.

So, is there anyway I could create a session-like variable on the server for the "path variable", and have it accessible on the server meteor.methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Mongo collection that acts as your temp-cache. Since there are handy packages, suchs as [dburles:mongo-collection-instances](https://github.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances), you can access this collection anywhere in your code where the collection has been created.

**server/main.js**

```
const TempCollection = new Mongo.Collection('temp');

Meteor.startup(()=>{

  // flush all temps at startup
  TempCollection.remove({});

});
```

**server/methods.js**

```js
Meteor.methods({

  storeTempDir() {

    const path = // ... get your temp dir from somewhere
    const key =  // ... give this path an id or key

    // the following requires dburles:mongo-collection-instances
    const TempCollection = Mongo.Collection.get('temp');
    TempCollection.insert({key, path});
  },

  doWithTempDir() {

    const key = // ... use a key to access the temp path

    // the following requires dburles:mongo-collection-instances
    const TempCollection = Mongo.Collection.get('temp');
    const path = TempCollection.insert({key});

    // ... do something with your path
  }

});
```

For a more modular approach, you can also create a Wrapper class around this:

**server/tmp.js**

```js
const TempCollection = new Mongo.Collection('temp');

Meteor.startup(()=>{

  // flush all temps at startup
  TempCollection.remove({});

});

export const tmp = {

  get(key) {
    TempCollection.findOne({key});
  }

  set(key, value) {
    const exist = this.get(key);
    if (exist)
      TempCollection.update(exist._id, { $set: { key, value } });
    else
      TempCollection.insert({key, value});
  }

}
```

And use it in your methods like so:

**server/methods.js**

```js
import { tmp } from './tmp.js';

Meteor.methods({

  storeTempDir() {

    const path = // ... get your temp dir from somewhere
    const key =  // ... give this path an id or key

    tmp.set(key, path);
  },

  doWithTempDir() {

    const key = // ... use a key to access the temp path

    const path = tmp.get(key).value;

    // ... do something with your path
  }

});
```

Some comments on this in order to keep it easy but safe:

- don't attach a schema to the TempCollection so you can have a real session-like behavior
- because this collection accepts anything, keep in mind that it should not be accessible by clients (they can use Session anyway).
- don't publish this content as it may be very sensitive information about internals
- don't overuse it. A good database design with well thought schemata is to be favored.
- maybe there are already packages out there that implement this exact behavior. Tested and production ready. These are to be favored, too.

Comment: Thank you very mush indeed for your detailed answer. I also figued out a solution that does not involve Mongo ... using Meteor method and Redux (cause I'm already using it)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that solves my issue using:

1. A Meteor method.
2. Redux store.

*I'm using React for the client-side*

Redux should be setup with a reducer called **tmpReducer** that has dirPath field, and a redux action for changing this dirPath field called: **changeTmpDirPath**

**tmpReducer**

```
import { CHANGE_TMP_DIR_PATH } from '../constants/actions';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  dirPath: ''
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_TMP_DIR_PATH: {
      return { dirPath: action.payload };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**changeTmpDirPath**

```
import { CHANGE_TMP_DIR_PATH } from '../constants/actions';

export const changeTmpDirPath = path => {
  return { type: CHANGE_TMP_DIR_PATH, payload: path };
};
```

**Then**: Create a Meteor method for creating tmp directory [returns DirPath as a result]

```
Meteor.methods({
  createTmpDir() {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      const tmpDir = tmp.dirSync();

      return tmpDir.name;
    }
  }
});
```

**Then**:

1. Call this Meteor method on the client's startup.
2. Pass the result of the Meteor method call to the Redux action to store the dirPath on the application level state [Redux Store].

   ```
    Meteor.call('createTmpDir', function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('createTmpDir err', err);
      } else {
        this.props.changeTmpDirPath(result); // Call Redux action
      }
   });
   ```
3. The dirPath will be then available as a Redux piece of state, and ready to be passed to any Meteor method that needs access to it.

   ```
   class MyComponent extends React.Component {

     componentDidMount() {
       Meteor.call('methodThatNeedDirPath', this.props.tmp.dirPath);
     }

     // ...

   const mapStateToProps = ({ tmp }) => ({ tmp });

   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
   ```

Comment: While this works, it goes against the other answer warning "_don't publish this content as it may be very sensitive information about internals_". A user could call a method with a tmp name that does not belong to them, and your server will happily provide access to that tmp folder content.

Comment: even if all the users who will be calling these Meteor methods are 'Admins' ?
one more question please ... Is Redux store accessible from the console  just like Meteor Session?